# Remove line breaks in csv using java

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi, line-breaks

I need to check for line breaks in csv for every entry using java. I have no idea how to do it. Can anybody help? thanks!

Comment: read the entry and check if one of the characters is \n

Comment: linebreaks are essential to the structure of an CSV file since they denote the ent of a "record". Meanwhile you only can try to count the field separator chars and hope, that the values at least do not contain them too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your java source from which you are reading the csv.

```
String col = columnName.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
reportColumn.put( "column", col );
```